# Vertically backward JPEG (or other) images in PDF streams

Tags: pdf, stream, jpeg

I am trying to understand the PDF format, and so far I have seen that images can appear in JPG format (but apparently without the "JFIF" bytes).

**Or, is it something different but very similar to JPEG?**

I am seeing that images appear reversed vertically.

**What is the purpose of this reversion?**

Can images appear normally in a PDF stream?

Here is an example from a PDF. As far as I know, this uploaded file is identical to the done contained in the PDF file, packed like this (using NASM assembly data definitions to make it simple):

```
db "19 0 obj",0x0D
db "<< /Type /XObject /Subtype /Image /Width 367 /Height 475 /BitsPerComponent 8 ",0x0D
db "/ColorSpace 12 0 R /Length 37575 /Filter /DCTDecode >> ",0x0D
db "stream",0x0D,0x0A
incbin "19_0_obj.bin.jpg"
db "endstream",0x0D
db "endobj",0x0D
```

[image]

Comment: How are you displaying the pixels of your images? Are you taking into account that the (0,0) coordinate in a PDF page is actually the bottom-left corner?

Comment: You also need to take into account the current transformation matrix at the "Do" operand inside the page where that image is being used.

Comment: That is just the raw image data and the PDF section where it is delimited. Thanks for your comment, I think I will check other PDF files to understand it well. It seems is just like in BMPs.

Comment: @alt.126: Don't look mainly at PDFs -- read the Spec.